# Tag suggestion - delta complexes

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are currently tags for [simplicial-complexes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplicial-complexes) and [cw-complexes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cw-complexes). The former has about 85 questions at the moment. A search for "delta complex" gives about 90 results, and there are often<sup>[[weasel words]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word)</sup> questions in [algebraic-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-topology) which discuss $\Delta$-complexes.

I have no experience with Meta and definitely none with tag creation, but I just thought that this might be a reasonable question to ask/tag to suggest, and I hope that that's the case (please let me know if not!).